# Wifi only works when connecting to a hotspot

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless

I freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop. I can connect to all the wireless networks in my home, but I have 80 to 100% packet loss. However, if I use my android phone to create a hotspot, I can connect to that with my laptop and have no packet loss.

I have no problems with the regular WiFi networks on other devices, and I can connect and use the wifi on the same laptop using Windows without any problems.

What can I do?

The command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` yields

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b2] (rev 73)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260 [8086:4262]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thank you, I have added the output.

Comment: What about `iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|cipher'`  What does this tell you the cipher being used are?

Comment: @Jeremy31 All my wifis have Group Cipher: CCMP and Pairwise Ciphers: CCMP